# PHP - XML with dots in element (Laravel)

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I use this parser package for Laravel: **https://github.com/orchestral/parser**

I have an XML which looks like this:

```
<MilestonesFollow-upReportUSERDEFINEDItem>
     <NextMilestoneDescCur.Comp.InclRltd>Description of the stone</NextMilestoneDescCur.Comp.InclRltd>
</MilestonesFollow-upReportUSERDEFINEDItem>
```

However, due to the element have dots `.` in it's name, it's treating it like a new element. This is how I parse it:

```
$data = $xml->parse([
     'milestones' => ['uses' => 'MilestonesFollow-upReportUSERDEFINEDItem[NextMilestoneDescCur.Comp.InclRltd]', 'default' => null]
]);
```

However, this gives me below array, which is split up by the dots `.`:

```
array:1 [▼
  "milestones" => array:524 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "NextMilestoneDescCur" => array:1 [▼
        "Comp" => array:1 [▼
          "InclRltd" => null
        ]
      ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Did you try to escape the dots with a slash? `\.`

Comment: Yes. The \. just gets printed out as well `"NextMilestoneDescCur\"` etc

Comment: The underlying parser method that this library uses ([here](https://github.com/laravie/parser/blob/master/src/helpers.php)) uses `.` as the separator between elements - it doesn't look like it's possible to use it on a document where the element names contain that character. I'd suggest opening a bug, since this is definitely a valid use-case.

Comment: Thanks Iainn! I've opened it as an issue and hopefully it'll be added in future versions!

Comment: Unless you need some specific feature provided by the library you can just do it in raw PHP - [demo](https://3v4l.org/4dnIf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is **not** supported by `Orchestral/Parser`:

I raised the issue with the developer:
https://github.com/laravie/parser/issues/18#event-1740422636, and he wrote:

```
 > Definitely not possible, sorry.
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a package that can help you parse your xml into an array.

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

```
$xml = '<MilestonesFollow-upReportUSERDEFINEDItem><NextMilestoneDescCur.Comp.InclRltd>Description of the stone</NextMilestoneDescCur.Comp.InclRltd></MilestonesFollow-upReportUSERDEFINEDItem>';

dd(xml_to_array($xml));
// Will yield: 

array:1 [▼
  "NextMilestoneDescCur.Comp.InclRltd" => "Description of the stone"
]
```